# How to bound the inverse Lipschitz of a function

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, lipschitz-functions

I have a map $f:\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}\times \mathbb{R}^n\to\Bbb R^n$ that takes a matrix $\mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ that is full rank and a vector $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ that is non-zero such that $f(\mathbf{A},\mathbf{x})=\mathbf{Ax}$. Let $v:=(\mathbf{A},\mathbf{x})$, I am looking to bound the following:
$$\frac{\lVert v-v'\rVert_2}{\lVert f(v)-f(v')\rVert_2}\leq L,$$
by some constant, say $L$. Would I be right in thinking that I could find $L$ by bounding the smallest eigenvalue of the derivative $\nabla f(v)$? The issue I face is that the map $f$ is not square (and not injective) so I can not use the classical inverse function theorem.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The function $f$ is bilinear, so I wouldn't expect calculus to help much (I'd rather try it directly). The best constant will depend on the choice of norm in $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n} \times \mathbb{R}^n$, so what is it? Are you looking for the best constant, or just any constant?

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz thanks for your reply. I have edited the original post to specify that the norm is the 2-norm. It doesn't have to be the best constant (it doesn't have to be particularly tight either), just a bound on the equation

Comment: For $v=(\mathbf{i},(1,0))$ and $v'=(\mathbf{1},(0,1))$ ($\mathbf{i}$ is the $90^\circ$ rotation, $\mathbf{1}$ is the identity) we have $v \neq v'$ and yet $f(v)=f(v')$. If I'm not mistaken, this shows that there's no such constant.

Comment: You are right, I tried to simplify the question as much as possible (but maybe I simplified it too much). Assume that $f(v)$ is identifiable upto scaling and permutation.

Comment: Apparently $f$ is not defined on all of $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}\times \mathbb{R}^n.$